# SSRS Multiple datasets - one from SQL Server database, one from Cube data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have two different datasets and the dataset querying from the SQL Server database has parameters FY and Quarter.

The second dataset which is pulling from the cube data has to use the same parameters as dataset 1 .How to add these parameters to the MDX query ?

...
    SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Over] } ON COLUMNS
    , NON EMPTY 
    { 
    ([Date].[FY].[FY Name].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Date].[FY].[FY].ALLMEMBERS 
    * [Org].[LevelID].[LevelID].ALLMEMBERS ) 
    } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON 
    ROWS 
    FROM [Ranking] 
    CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, 
    FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
...

Comment: Parameters are added at the report level and they can be used in both data sets.

Comment: Should I add a filter to the data from dataset 2  using the parameters from DS1 ?

Comment: Why not send them in as a parameter on the command that fetches data?

Comment: For example, if your report has the Parameter  -->@UserId then that parameter can be used as an input parameter on Dataset1...DatasetX.

Comment: For Dataset 2 I have MDX query and the parameter (dataset 1 )on the report is not a field in dataset 2